# Embed custom font family into WebView

Tags: c#, html, css, windows-phone-8.1

I want to use custom (Open Sans) font in my app.

When I use

```
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
</style>
```

all works fine (with blinking when font loaded) but it works.

When I replace `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans')` to

```
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/K88pR3goAWT7BTt32Z01mxJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/RjgO7rYTmqiVp7vzi-Q5URJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/LWCjsQkB6EMdfHrEVqA1KRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/xozscpT2726on7jbcb_pAhJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/59ZRklaO5bWGqF5A9baEERJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/u-WUoqrET9fUeobQW7jkRRJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3VtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

my solution doesn't work.

I want to download all fonts and use font like code bellow:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(ms-appx-web:///cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3VtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
    unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

where `url(ms-appx-web:///cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3VtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2)` path to font in my app

Also, I noticed, that this solution

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        /* latin */
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Open Sans';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(ms-appx-web:///cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3VtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
            unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
        }

        .gloria {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="gloria">
        Gloria Hallelujah!
        glory one
        glory two

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

works for Windows 8.1 Store Application but not for Windows Phone 8.1 and I don't know where is my mistake.

Thank in advance